# SQLAlchemy: Initializing attribute based on other attribute

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a Python project using SQLAlchemy. I have following class (I have omitted some methods irrelevant to the question):

```
class Cmd(Base):
    __tablename__ = "commands"
    dbid = Column(Integer, Sequence("commands_seq"), primary_key = True)
    cmd_id = Column(SmallInteger)
    instance_dbid =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey("instances.dbid"))
    type = Column(String(20))

    __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_on" : type,
    "polymorphic_identity" : "Cmd"
    }

    def __init__(self, cmd_id):
        self.cmd_id = cmd_id
        self.cmd_name = event_names[self.cmd_id]
```

As you see, on initializing instance of the class the attribute `cmd_name` is created from `cmd_id` attribute using `event_names` list (also omitted, it's a simple list containing command names).

I create object `Cmd`, add it session, commit session. After closing application and launching it again I try to load this `Cmd` using SQLAlchemy query. The object is loaded, but of course `__init__` is not called and `cmd_name` is not set.

I would like to know if there is some simple way of executing some code (`self.cmd_name = event_names[self.cmd_id]`) after getting `Cmd` object with query. Of course I could do a special method and always launch it after query, but I'm seeking more elegant, automatic way.

I've read the documentation and found some information about ORM Event listeners, but they seem to be too much for such simple case. I've also found piece about Attribute Events, but they work with `column_property` and `relationship` only. Is there any short, elegant way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @reconstructor decorator:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import reconstructor
class Cmd(Base):
    __tablename__ = "commands"
    dbid = Column(Integer, Sequence("commands_seq"), primary_key = True)
    cmd_id = Column(SmallInteger)
    instance_dbid =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey("instances.dbid"))
    type = Column(String(20))

    __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_on" : type,
    "polymorphic_identity" : "Cmd"
    }

    def __init__(self, cmd_id):
        self.cmd_id = cmd_id
        self.cmd_name = event_names[self.cmd_id]

    @reconstructor
    def init_db_load(self):
        self.cmd_name = event_names[self.cmd_id]
```

See this [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html) under "Constructors and Object Initialization".

Comment: I knew there HAS TO be something simpler than mapper event listeners :)