# How to use SQL Alchemy and SQL Alchemy Utils URLType so it only saves the hostname?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I'm using SQL Alchemy and SQL Alchemy Utils [URLType](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.url) in a project currently and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to sanitize the input of SQLAlchemy attribute so that the only thing stored in the database is the host of the furl object. Currently I've solved it by just calling a class method prior to each set operation like so:

```
class Website(Base, Timestamp):
    __tablename__ = "websites"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Data
    origin = Column(URLType, nullable=False, unique=True)

    # Functions
    @classmethod
    def prep_url(cls, url):
        return url.origin

x = furl('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')
ws = Website(origin=Website.prep_url(x))
>>> ws.origin
stackoverflow.com
```

While I'd like to be able to use it like so:

```
ws = Website(origin=x)
>>> ws.origin
stackoverflow.com
```

I thought perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17454860/1021259) was what I was looking for, but I can't find the documentation for it.

Comment: Just realized the example I gave here is kind of bad because I could solve it with a custom constructor. That's not quite what I want, I want to be able to set the attribute on its own.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [property/setter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property)?

```
class Website(Base, Timestamp):
    __tablename__ = "websites"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Data
    origin_ = Column("origin", URLType, nullable=False, unique=True)

    @property
    def origin(self):
        return self.origin_

    @origin.setter
    def origin(self, url):
        self.origin_ = url.origin

x = furl('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')
ws = Website(origin=x)
>>> ws.origin
stackoverflow.com
```